# Get current device information of the user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, device

I have a MVC3 application.

Now i want to retrieve the information that the user is opening my application on which device.
Whether it is an iPHONE, Tablet or anything else?

Secondly, I want to retrieve the browser information and the screen width and height of the current browser of the user i.e. the current resolution.

How can i get all these information?

Thanks

Comment: @Karthik I have googled around. Finding the screens resolution is easy. But finding the users device is not mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the [UserAgent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent.aspx) will give you all the information that is possible to get.

If you really want more detailed information regarding mobile devices, then I suggest using the [51Degrees.mobi library](http://nuget.org/packages/51Degrees.mobi/).

The only way to get a user's screen resolution is via JavaScript, which means you are going to have to create some kind of service to send that information to the server.

You can use `screen.width` and `screen.height` to get the info and then do something like this to post to the server.

```
$.ajax({
   url:'/api/UserData'
   type:'POST',
   data: {
      width: screen.width,
      height: screen.height
   }
});
```